# Running a component without setting up any routing

Tags: angular

I'm not sure if this is a simple question or not, but I am new to Angular and am wondering if there is a simple way to run a component for testing without setting up any routing? Like I have an existing project, I just added a new component with a form using CLI and I want to just simply navigate to that component so I can test it as I write it.

Comment: Why do you want to add new component if you don't want to configure route? Just try whatever you need in app.coponent.ts, it's the default component from where angular app start and it doesn't require a route

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would to be just include the component in your base component like so add the selector like so

```
<app-home></app-home>
```

and you will see your component in your base component without having to navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

when you create a component you have Ts.file in your ts file have a component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
```

Your Tag is

```
<app-task></app-task>
```

***try this way***